# load custom world in gazebo from a launch file

Tags: ros, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've built a custom wold for gazebo (dae file) and I'm trying to load this file from a launch file. When I run the world file directly from gazebo, it woks and I can see the world (gazebo maze.world). But when I build a launch file and include the world file inside the launch file, I get the following error:

```
Error [SystemPaths.cc:367] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [Visual.cc:2138] No mesh specified
```

Here is the content of the world file (maze.world):

[image: image description]

and here is the launch file(maze.launch):

[image: image description]

both launch file and world file are in the same directory and I've set the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH to that directory. Can someone tell me what's the problem here? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Indigo, and gazebo_ros.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7544/load-custom-world-in-gazebo-from-a-launch-file/) by [Kasra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1036/kasra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think the problem may be related to how the mesh file location is specified:

`<mesh><uri>file://maze_parallel_wall.dae</uri></mesh>`

I would recommend following an example from `gazebo_models`, such as the [cordless drill](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/66fa0c90f5384decfd7e16802e4cfb8872297b17/cordless_drill/model.sdf#cl-21):

`<mesh><uri>model://cordless_drill/meshes/cordless_drill.stl</uri></mesh>`

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1